# Redactor: Accessing a callback within plugin

Tags: javascript, redactor

I'm building a plugin for Redactor 10 and I want to access the [syncBeforeCallback](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/callbacks/sync/#callback-syncBeforeCallback) callback from within my plugin.

I can access it whilst initialising redactor which is shown in the docs page linked above but I don't know how I can access it from within my plugin. I want my plugin to do something on that callback.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a response from Redactor support on this:

Here's how you could access this callback from your plugin:

This one is for Redactor itself:

```
$('#redactor').redactor({
    syncBeforeCallback: function(html)
    {
        return this.myplugin.get(html);
    }
});
```

and here's the plugin accessing syncBeforeCallback data:

```
if (!RedactorPlugins) var RedactorPlugins = {};

RedactorPlugins.myplugin = function() {
    return {
        get: function(html)
        {
            // do somethings ...
            return html;
        }
    }
};
```